# Running Jasmine tests in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, jasmine

I'm having difficulty running ES6 Jasmine tests in a browser other than IE11 direct from Visual Studio 2017.

I'm running all tests using Ctrl R, A which automatically opens an IE11 browser.  This obviously causes issues with ES6.

My default browser is set to Chrome and .html and .htm file extensions are set to open with Chrome by default.

Is there another setting I'm missing?

Comment: Right Click file > Browse With > Choose Chrome > Click "Set as Default" > Click Browse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configured the browser properly in Karma js. Please go through the following link for some more ideas
http://karma-runner.github.io/3.0/config/browsers.html